# BT878 PCI TVCARD to capture analog video signal on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, video

I have a **PCI Pinnacle PCTV Pro** installed on Kubuntu 18.04.

Using the following command

```
lspci -k
```

seems that the PCI card was detected:

```
(...) 
    02:0b.0 Multimedia video controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Video Capture (rev 11)
            Subsystem: Pinnacle Systems Inc. PCTV pro (TV + FM stereo receiver)
            Kernel driver in use: bttv
            Kernel modules: bttv
    02:0b.1 Multimedia controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture (rev 11)
            Subsystem: Pinnacle Systems Inc. PCTV pro (TV + FM stereo receiver, audio section)
            Kernel driver in use: snd_bt87x
            Kernel modules: snd_bt87x
    40:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV38GL [Quadro FX 1300] (rev a2)
            Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation NV38GL [Quadro FX 1300]
            Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
(...)
```

However, since this is an analog PCTV capture card, perhaps this is the reason why Kaffeine doesn't detect any kind of signal for channels capture. I'm not really sure about that.

I found also that in the GUI System settings, the card reference is only viewable as a audio card in the menu 'Audio Recording'. Nothig is viewable in the menu 'Video Recording'.

My questions are:

1. Is it necessary to do any additional configuration?
2. Shall I get specific software in order to put this thing to work? If yes, which one is the more suitable?

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Try using the application cheese to see if that recognizes the input video source.

Comment: It recognized, yes as on the 'preferences', the Webcam assumed the Bt878 video card. However, it doesn't seems to be used as a Webcam hardware: there was an error saying "There was an error playing video from the webcam".
And Kaffeine was as useless as always...

Comment: Surprisingly little information about this on the web!  Someone suggests using `mythtv`, available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I tried `mythtv` but gave up. They only offer the source code, and it must be compiled for the particular version of Linux. Since I'm not a technician, I'm looking for other ways to solve my problem.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's available in the Ubuntu repositories (compiled already) = enter the command `sudo apt install mythtv` or install it using the Ubuntu software center.

Comment: That is the easy part, my friend! That is the frontend of the program, which is not reacheable, as one must to mount a Mysql backend server, be part of a 'group' and other freaky things. In the middle of the process, there are a lot of info to 'correct' a different variety of errors that may happen during this 'simple' process. And, of course, no TV whatsoever.
I shall quote what someone said: "I don't think anything has ever been more surprisingly difficult than trying to set up any decent TV-watching application under Ubuntu/Linux."

Comment: Ug - I had no idea!  mysql is not too bad to setup, and groups by themselves are not really tough either, but I've never dealth with the TV interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tvtime`.

```
sudo apt-get install tvtime.
```

Comment: Why suggest tvtime when it does not even support capture? He asked for software to capture with.